# Trabalhando com diretorio com caracteres especiais

Tags: powershell

Tenho o seguinte script:

```
$ExistPath = Test-Path -PathType container  C:\Publicação\SQL-Release\Services 


if ($ExistPath)
 {
     Write-Host "Removendo diretorio!"
     Remove-Item -Path C:\Publicação\SQL-Release\Services -Recurse -Force
 }

 Write-Host "Criando diretorio!"
 New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path C:\Publicação\SQL-Release\Services

 Copy-Item .\Services\MyServices\bin\Release C:\Publicação\SQL-Release\Services\Nalin -Recurse
```

Porém quando executo ele cria um diretório com caracteres bem diferentes do esperado. No caso:

```
C:\PublicaÃ§Ã£o
```

Como resolver?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você precisa mudar a codificação (*encoding*) do script através do comando `chcp`.

Em termos resumidos, o comando muda o *encoding* no qual seu script é interpretado pelo powershell. A página de código padrão para o idioma português é a 860, então utilizar o seguinte comando antes do resto do script deve resolver o problema:

```
chcp 860
```

Note que chamar o comando sem argumentos faz com que o Powershell imprima na tela a página de código que estiver em uso no momento.

[Link para a documentação do comando](https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb490874.aspx), caso você tenha curiosidade, ou precise fazer mais coisas relacionadas a isso no futuro.

P.s.: a documentação não menciona, mas existem páginas de código com números bem mais altos. As páginas não documentadas podem representar, por exemplo, UNICODE. Acredito, no entanto, que a página 860 já é suficiente para resolver o problema da pergunta.

Comment: Executei o script aqui no meu computador e funcionou, criou o diretório corretamente [C:\Publicação\SQL-Release\Services], é normal haver essa divergência de codificação?

Comment: Coloquei o comando como primeira linha do meu script e não funcionou como esperava. Porém quando alterei a forma como o arquivo do script de UTF-8 para UTF-8 with BOM passou funcionar.

Comment: @Mathias até onde eu sei o console do Powershell já abre com uma codificação padrão selecionada. Não sei se esse comportamento se repete em todas as versões do console, ou mesmo do Windows (pois isso pode ser do sistema e não do Powershell em si).

Comment: @RodolphoSa o BOM altera o *encoding* do arquivo, então deve ser isso.